# Show that any vertex $v$ of $P$ is half-integral.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

Let $G$ be an undirected graph and define

$$P=\{x \in R^{V}: x(u)+x(v) \leq 1 \:\:\text{for all edges}\:\: e=uv,\:\: x \geq 0\}$$

Show that any vertex $v$ of $P$ is half integral.

Comment: What does it mean for a vertex to be half-integral? Does it mean $2x(v)$ is an integer? Anyway, suppose $G$ is the two vertices $u$ and $v$ with the one edge $uv$, and $x(u)=.1$, and $x(v)=.2$. This would seem to satisfy the hypotheses, but not the conclusion.

Comment: @ Gerry: You found a feasible point, which need not even be on the boundary, let alone a vertex. ... My suggestion is to look up "complementary slackness", since for any vertex of a polytope, you can find a linear function which is maximized there (and only there).

Comment: @Carl, I missed that the question was about a vertex of $P$, not a vertex of $G$. I note in my defense that OP used the same symbol, $v$, with both meanings.

Comment: @ Gerry: Yeah, math terms tend to be overused. (And it's actually Chris. When I created my StackExchange account, I was logged into my "junk" account.)

Comment: @Carl, you wouldn't be notified if I used "Chris". And I don't get notified when you leave a space between the at-sign and the Gerry.

Comment: @Gerry: Oh, stackexchange actually sends notifications? I did not know that. (Different rules for different forums.)